# sustitution of '\n' for another character doesn´t work properly

Tags: java

I have the next little code, it has to read a file and when it finds an `\n` or an `\r` it substitutes it with a `$`. The file is this:

```
for A27y= + 1643.2 - 642 : b
end

F017 = 3.5
```

and here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int car;
        String l = "";
        try
        {
            File file = new File("openFile.txt");           
            RandomAccessFile af = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r");           
            while((car = af.read()) != -1)
               l += (char)car;
            l = l.replace('\n', '$').replace('\r', '$');
            System.out.println(""+l);
            af.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot open file");
        }
    }
```

The problem that I have is that every time it finds an '\n' or an '\r' in the file, instead of printing a single `$` it prints it double `$$`, and I don't understand why.

It prints something like this:

> for A27y= + 1643.2 - 642 : b$$end$$$$F017 = 3.5$$

when it should be like this:

> for A27y= + 1643.2 - 642 : b$end$$F017 = 3.5$

Comment: Some systems use `\r\n` for new lines, so this is not that strange.

Comment: Most notably, windows uses \r\n as the line separator.

Answer (score 3):

Since some systems (Windows for example) use `\r\n` to represent end of line, you will sometimes get this behaviour for the code you are showing. You can fix this by first replacing these:

```
l = l.replace("\r\n", "$").replace('\n', '$').replace('\r', '$');
```

Comment: Isn't L gonna be a single character at a time?

Comment: `l` is a string containing the entire file when it comes to this line.

Answer (score 0):

you can check what Keppil said by looking at the values of car in the debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can try as @Keppil suggested (probadly the "\r\n" is a line feed at your system).
I'd suggest making things more efficient and short by not iterating through each character in the file:

```
String text = readFileAsString("textfile.txt").replace("\n", "$").replace("\r", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is what the task actually is.

If it's about finding actual <kbd>CR</kbd> and <kbd>LF</kbd> characters in the text and replacing each with a dollar sign, then you are getting the correct output. As others have already explained - on Windows each newline is composed of <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> together.

If it's about finding newlines, and replacing each newline with a dollar sign, then you first need to ask yourself how you define a newline. What if you have a file where there are some separate <kbd>CR</kbd>s, some separate <kbd>LF</kbd>s and some together? If you want individual <kbd>CR</kbd> and <kbd>LF</kbd> characters to be replaced with `$` but also <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> to be replaced by a single `$`, you could try:

```
        char lastChar = `\0`;
        while((car = af.read()) != -1) {
           char currChar = (char)car;
           if ( currChar == `\n` && lastChar != `\r` || currChar == `\r` ) {
              l += '$';
           } else {
              l += currChar;
           }
           lastChar = currChar;
        }
```

If, however, you want to replace only what Windows considers a newline (that is, if the file is on Windows, only <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd> are newlines so only they should be replaced with `$`), then you might change that to:

```
        char lastChar = `\0`;
        while((car = af.read()) != -1) {
           char currChar = (char)car;
           if ( currChar == `\n` && lastChar == `\r` ) {
              l += '$'
           } else {
              l += currChar;
           }
           lastChar = currChar;
        }
```

This will keep individual <kbd>CR</kbd> and <kbd>LF</kbd>  characters as they were, and only replace "real newline" combinations.

So choose your definition, and you have your implementation.